# How dose it work? (about map function in Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I can't understand below logic.
I think when put 'a' into () in result, the value of result is 32.
Because of (0 until 1-1 -> 0), lastDays[it] is 31.
So result is 31 + 1 = 32.
But the value is 1.
I am studying Kotlin now.

```
val a = 1
var b = 1

val lastDays = listOf(31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)

val result = (0 until a - 1).map {
    lastDays[it]
}.sum() + b
```

Please borrow me your wisdom.

Comment: Maybe `result` boils down to the value of `b`? Looks like you didn't actually `map` anything by using `(0 until a - 1)`, which is `(0 until 1 - 1)` and therefore `(0 until 0)`. Use `var a = 2` and receive a `result` with the value 32.

Comment: Note that `until` excludes the value specified as the end of the range. The result you described in the question would apply if the range were specified as `0..(a-1)` or `0 until a`.

Answer (score 4):

`0 until a - 1` results in `0 until 0`, so it is an empty range. Mapping the empty range results in an empty list. Calling `sum()` on an empty list returns 0. Then you add `0 + b` where `b` is 1.

Comment: I should have made my comment an answer ;-) +1